nextcloud wont let my android app login; too many attemtps
So I just set up nextcloud with the AIO docker image.
Can login on the web just fine, but when trying to login via the android app it says HTTP operation failed with code 429 (too many attempts).
But that was the first try to login.
Not sure what is going on.

So I found the answer, in the apache logs it said the UPD buffer size was too small and gave a link to this git:
github.com/quic-go/wiki/UDP-Buffer-Sizes
said to incrase the net.core.rmem_max and wmem_max to 7500000 (7.5Mb)
I did that and it fixed the issue.
Now to make it persistant through reboots I edited the /etc/sysctl.conf file by adding these lines to the bottom:
net.core.rmem_max = 7500000
net.core.wmem_max = 7500000

apply the changes with sudo sysctl -p and bam! all good
